# Bypass <app-route> to make normal links work in Polymer 2

Tags: polymer, url-routing, polymer-2.x, polymer-elements, app-route

My site uses Polymer 2, `<app-location>` and `<app-route>`. The `<app-route>` allows me to change the URL on user interaction with the app, but it seems that it is also preventing normal links from functioning.

How can I make normal `<a href="/some/url/on/my/domain">` links work? Is there a way to make links bypass `<app-route>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't get the answer by user2438933 to work, but this seems to do the trick!

```
<a href="/some/url" onclick="normalLinkClick(event)">
...
normalLinkClick(event){
  event.stopPropagation()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `app-location` use `iron-location` which listen click event on document. So just stop click event before it propagates to document.

```
<a href='/some/url' on-click='stopPropagation'>
...
stopPropagation (event) {
  event.stopPropagation()
}
```

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work... I tried both `on-click` and `on-tap`, but my event handler is never fired?

Comment: `onclick` is a native attribute but `on-click` is a polymer annotated [see](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events). IMHO I really recommend to not use `onclick` its need a global scope function. If you not comfortable to use `on-*`, use `addEventListener` instead.